# 3 div , one fixed width

Tags: html, css

I am not sure if this is possible plainly in html css.

I have 3 divs in one line
the 2nd div must occupy 200px width and the first & last div must occupy remaining width .

http://jsfiddle.net/Garav/gk9t3/

the remaining two divs are fixed at 100px in fiddle . is there a way to make them fill the remaining of the screen equally on both the sides , so that the 2nd div always remains at center ?

Note : the width of parent div is not fixed .

Comment: Do you want the divs on the margin to contain something, or just to fill the empty space, and the middle one to be centered. Would it be ok if the middle div is inside another div with 100% width, and centered?

Comment: middle one to be centered and the rest 2 divs will basically have a background repeat image occupying remaining space

Comment: ok. I'll post a solution. Check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use margin: 0 auto; no need for margin divs: http://jsfiddle.net/gk9t3/3/

Comment: You can add the background image to the parent div.

Comment: assuming that the page has a background.. and the centre image has transparent parts somewhere .. so obviously you wouldn't want the ".fill-remaining" backgroud to be visible under the transparent part of centre image

Comment: Well, depends on your page. There was no info about how tiling is supposed to be done. In any case, adding two divs just for styling purposes is bad (div soup). See http://jsfiddle.net/gk9t3/27/ for another solution. Page has red background, center div also.

Answer (score 3):

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/5Br5A/

CSS

```
.image-placeholder{
    background: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    height : 200px;
    clear:none;
    float: left;
}
.fill-remaining {
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    clear:none;
}
.fill-remaining.left {
    background:#f00;
    float: left;
    margin-right:-100px;
}
.fill-remaining.left>div {
    padding-right: 100px;
}
.fill-remaining.right {
    background:#00f;
    float: right;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
.fill-remaining.right>div {
    padding-left: 100px;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="fill-remaining left">
</div>
<div class="fill-remaining right">
</div>
<div class="image-placeholder">
</div>
```

Comment: cool solution bro.. now I have to weigh between -ve margin & table properties

Comment: Updated in case you would use the sidebars for content.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the middle div inside another div, and centered it. See if this fits your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/gk9t3/1/

Comment: 200px need not always be 20% .. think abt mobile devices

Comment: You can set the desired width to .image-placeholder in the css part. It can be 200px, or 20%, or how much you want :)

Comment: thats what I don't want to set individually for mobile , pads , desktops